# XSL copy only 'part' of a string

Tags: xml, xpath, copy

So, I've got this XSL that I need to copy only 'part' of a Patient name.  The only part I want copied is the 'Last Name' and 'First Name'.  If a middle initial or middle name exists, that part needs to be ignored.  The names are always separated by carets, '^', so that could be an easy way to ignore the middle name or initial, if they exist & they don't always appear.  Some patients only come over with a 'Last name' & 'First Name'.

**EDIT:**

if the patient only comes over with a 'Last Name' & 'First Name' then it would look like 'Doe^John', which is what I would like to copy, so there would be no second caret.

This is running in JBOSS 4.x with XALAN

**This is my stylesheet:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/dataset">
<dataset>
<!-- Specific Character Set -->
<xsl:copy-of select="attr[@tag='00080005']"/>
<!-- Admitting Diagnoses Description -->
<attr tag="00081080" vr="LO"/>
<!-- Referring Physican Name -->
<attr tag="00080090" vr="PN"/>
<!-- Patient Name -->
<xsl:copy-of select="attr[@tag='00100010']"/>
<!-- Patient Birthdate -->
<xsl:copy-of select="attr[@tag='00100030']"/>
<!--Patient ID -->
<attr tag="00100020" vr="LO"/>
</dataset>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the above code, I'm only wanting to copy 'part' of the Patients' name and the date of birth.  Right now, its copying the entire value of the patients name.

**this is the input that it would get the information from:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
<attr tag="00080008" vr="CS" pos="0" name="Image Type" vm="2" len="18">ORIGINAL\SECONDARY</attr>
<attr tag="00080016" vr="UI" pos="26" name="SOP Class UID" vm="1" len="26">1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.7</attr>
<attr tag="00080018" vr="UI" pos="60" name="SOP Instance UID" vm="1" len="56">1.3.6.1.4.1.23849.372900571.11.1635314520851301288.2.2.1</attr>
<attr tag="00080020" vr="DA" pos="124" name="Study Date" vm="1" len="8">20140326</attr>
<attr tag="00080022" vr="DA" pos="140" name="Acquisition Date" vm="1" len="8">20140326</attr>
<attr tag="00080030" vr="TM" pos="156" name="Study Time" vm="1" len="6">173426</attr>
<attr tag="00080032" vr="TM" pos="170" name="Acquisition Time" vm="1" len="6">173426</attr>
<attr tag="00080050" vr="SH" pos="-1" name="Accession Number" vm="1" len="3">OUT</attr>
<attr tag="00080054" vr="AE" pos="-1" name="Retrieve AE Title" vm="1" len="8">RADARCH2</attr>
<attr tag="00080060" vr="CS" pos="202" name="Modality" vm="1" len="2">CT</attr>
<attr tag="00080061" vr="CS" pos="212" name="Modalities in Study" vm="1" len="2">CT</attr>
<attr tag="00080064" vr="CS" pos="222" name="Conversion Type" vm="1" len="4">WSD</attr>
<attr tag="00080070" vr="LO" pos="234" name="Manufacturer" vm="0" len="0"/>
<attr tag="00080080" vr="LO" pos="242" name="Institution Name" vm="0" len="0"/>
<attr tag="00080090" vr="PN" pos="250" name="Referring Physician's Name" vm="1" len="20">DOC^TEST^TESTES</attr>
<attr tag="00081010" vr="SH" pos="278" name="Station Name" vm="0" len="0"/>
<attr tag="00081030" vr="LO" pos="286" name="Study Description" vm="1" len="20">CT HEAD W/O CONTRAST</attr>
<attr tag="0008103E" vr="LO" pos="314" name="Series Description" vm="0" len="0"/>
<attr tag="00081040" vr="LO" pos="322" name="Institutional Department Name" vm="0" len="0"/>
<attr tag="00081070" vr="PN" pos="330" name="Operator's Name" vm="0" len="0"/>
<attr tag="00081090" vr="LO" pos="338" name="Manufacturer's Model Name" vm="0" len="0"/>
<attr tag="00100010" vr="PN" pos="346" name="Patient's Name" vm="1" len="16">DOE^JOHN^BOY</attr>
<attr tag="00100020" vr="LO" pos="370" name="Patient ID" vm="1" len="8">123456</attr>
<attr tag="00100021" vr="LO" pos="-1" name="Issuer of Patient ID" vm="1" len="4">HOSP</attr>
<attr tag="00100030" vr="DA" pos="394" name="Patient's Birth Date" vm="1" len="8">19010101</attr>
<attr tag="00100040" vr="CS" pos="410" name="Patient's Sex" vm="1" len="2">M</attr>
</dataset>
```

from the input above, the Patients' name is 'DOE^JOHN^BOY' and I would like the copy-of select statement to only copy 'DOE^JOHN'.  How would I go about this?  Would I use a 'substring-before' function somehow?

thanks

**EDIT #2**

Just thought I would post the code I have now that works as expected.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/dataset">
<dataset>
<xsl:variable name="modPatName" select="attr[@tag='00100010']"/>
<xsl:variable name="before-first" select="substring-before($modPatName, '^')"/>
<xsl:variable name="after-first" select="substring-after($modPatName, '^')"/>
<!-- Specific Character Set -->
<xsl:copy-of select="attr[@tag='00080005']"/>
<!-- Admitting Diagnoses Description -->
<attr tag="00081080" vr="LO"/>
<!-- Referring Physican Name -->
<attr tag="00080090" vr="PN"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($after-first, '^')">
        <attr tag="00100010" vr="PN">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($before-first, '^', substring-before($after-first, '^'))"/>
        </attr>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
            <attr tag="00100010" vr="PN">
                <xsl:value-of select="$modPatName"/>
            </attr>
    </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
<!--<xsl:copy-of select="attr[@tag='00100010']"/> -->
<xsl:copy-of select="attr[@tag='00100030']"/>
<!--Patient ID -->
<attr tag="00100020" vr="LO"/>
</dataset>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, you would use a `substring-before` function somehow.  What have you tried?  This is really just about XPath, not XSLT.

Comment: @harpo thx, I've edited the tags in this post.   I wasn't sure how to tell substring-before to only look at what is before the 2nd caret, & drop that 2nd caret, if it does exist in some cases.  Now that I think about it, it probably would not copy the 2nd caret.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I said this was just about XPath, but you do probably want to use some XSLT.  There's no single function call to get the substring before the *Nth* occurrence of a substring.

I reduced the input for simplicity to:

```
<names>
    <name>WILKES^JOHN^BOOTH</name>
    <name>MADONNA</name>
    <name>DOE^JOHN^BOY</name>
    <name>ELON^MUSK</name>
</names>
```

With the following transform,

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/names">
        <xsl:for-each select="name">
            <xsl:variable name="before-first" select="substring-before(., '^')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="after-first" select="substring-after(., '^')"/>

            <name>
                <xsl:choose>

                    <xsl:when test="contains($after-first, '^')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($before-first, '^', substring-before($after-first, '^'))"/>
                    </xsl:when>

                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>

                </xsl:choose>
            </name>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

You get

```
<name>WILKES^JOHN</name>
<name>MADONNA</name>
<name>DOE^JOHN</name>
<name>ELON^MUSK</name>
```

Which I think is what you want.

There are [pure-XPath](http://www.xml.org//sites/www.xml.org/files/xslt_efficient_programming_techniques.pdf) ways to do inline branching (the "Oliver Becker"), i.e. without the `choose`.  But it's even uglier than the above.

Comment: thanks harpo for looking at this.  :)  I'll try it 1st thing tomorrow.

Comment: Note that since you're in Java, there's really nothing stopping you moving to XSLT 2.0, which would make this a one-liner: `string-join(subsequence(tokenize(., '\^'), 1, 2), '^')`

Comment: It would be so nice to nice XSLT 2.0, but I can't figure out how to make the JAVAX call the SAXON transformer within JBOSS 4.x.x.  Not enough knowledge.  I can only hope that the next version of our system we use upgrades to JBOSS 7.

Comment: @Docjay, yes, I feel the same way in .NET — although Michael Kay is making it harder to say "I wish I could use XSLT 2.0 on platform X" ;)